# How do I set a specific entry in a template with "set"

Tags: entries, set

This won't work in a template:

```twig
{% set entry = craft.entries.id(43) %}<h1>Titel: {{ entry.title }}</h1>
```

But this does:

```twig
{% for entry in craft.entries.id(43) %}<h1>Titel: {{ entry.title }}</h1>{% endfor %}
```

Is it really necessary to use the for loop? I tried to use set because I'd like to over rule the entry variable for the whole template that I'm using if a specific url is visited

```twig
{% if craft.request.segment(2)=="openings-en-trainingstijden" %} {% set entry = craft.entries.id(43) %}{% endif %} {{ entry.title }} etc..
```

Another example this code:

```twig
{% for entry1 in craft.entries.id(43) %}Titel: {{ entry1.title }}{% endfor %}
{% set entry2 = craft.entries.id(43) %}Titel: {{ entry2.title }}
```

Results in:

```html
Titel: Openings- en trainingstijden
Titel:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `.first` where you are setting the `entry` variable:

`{% set entry = craft.entries.id(43).first %}`

That way you can avoid doing a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your first line must work. But there is a typo with double `))`

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.id(43).first() %}

{{ entry.title}}
```

But normally when you add a template for a specific single you doesn't have to set the entry.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't... even with a single )

Comment: Sorry forgot the .first()